# How can I compare a field to another field in a different list through a SOQL WHERE clause?

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller-extension

I am building a Visualforce PDF page with a controller extension to display details from the parent object and child object in the same table. The table's first two columns reference the *records* list from the extension to provide high level information and then the third column references the *records2* list from the extension to retrieve all of the activity records related to the *records* list.

The architecture is the Visualforce page references the standard controller for the SalesPlan__c object and also references a controller extension. There is a child object of SalesPlan__c called SalesPlanGoal__c where high level objectives are captured. Then there is a child of SalesPlanGoal__c called SalesPlanActivity__c where actionable tasks are noted. SMART_Goal__c is the name of the lookup field for SalesPlanGoal__c object on SalesPlanActivity__c.

I have no problem displaying the Name and Description of the SalesPlanGoal__c records as separate rows in a table (i.e. Initiative and SMART Goals columns in image below). I am struggling with filtering the SalesPlanActivity__c records to show in the third column (i.e. Benchmark Activities) with their corresponding SalesPlanGoal__c record. I am currently displaying all SalesPlanActivity__c records for the SalesPlan__c on each SalesPlanGoal__c instead of having all the SalesPlanActivity__c records specific to a SalesPlanGoal__c.

[image]

Below is my controller extension:

```
public with sharing class SalesPlanPDFExtension{

public List<SalesPlanGoal__c> records = new List<SalesPlanGoal__c>();
public List<SalesPlanActivity__c> records2 = new List<SalesPlanActivity__c>();

public List<SalesPlanGoal__c> getrecords() {    
    return records;
}
public List<SalesPlanActivity__c> getrecords2() {    
    return records2;
}
    /*Constructor*/
    public void SalesPlanPDFExtension() {  
    }/*End Constructor*/

    /*Constructor*/
    public SalesPlanPDFExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        records = [SELECT Id,Name,Description__c,Sales_Plan__c,SMART_Goal__c,Key_Initiative__c
                        /*,
                        (SELECT Id,Name,Account__c,Contact__c,Key_Initiative__c,Sales_Plan__c,SMART_Goal__c,Status__c,Subject__c 
                        FROM BenchmarkActivities__r)
                        */
                   FROM SalesPlanGoal__c 
                   WHERE Sales_Plan__c=:ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')
                   ORDER BY Name ASC
                  ];
        records2 = [SELECT Id,Name,Account__c,Contact__c,Due_Date__c,Key_Initiative__c,Sales_Plan__c,SMART_Goal__c,SMART_Goal_Objective__c,Status__c,Subject__c
                    FROM SalesPlanActivity__c 
                    WHERE SMART_Goal__c IN :records
                    //AND Key_Initiative__c = 'Exteriors'
                    ORDER BY Key_Initiative__c ASC
                   ]; 
    }
    /*End Constructor*/
   }
```

I can get the SalesPlanActivity__c to filter if I add a text literal match to the WHERE statement in *records2* such as `Key_Initiative__c = 'Exteriors'` but I need it do be more dynamic than that because then the SalesPlanActivity__c records for a different initiative/goal type only shows the SalesPlanGoal__c *Exteriors* SalesPlanActivity__c records. I would ideally like something like `WHERE SMART_Goal__c IN :records AND Key_Initiative__c = records.Name`.

I figure I need something like records[i].name where i is the iteration of the row, but I have no idea how to accomplish this.

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Will you please help?

Comment: Your title seems a little misleading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking to do a collection comparison, it is fairly straightforward. Use the `IN` operator as you do with your `Id` check, and build up a collection of the values you are looking for. It is a little unusual because you can check if an `Id` is in a collection of `SObject`, normally you need your collection to be of the same type as the field you are trying to filter.

```
Set<String> goalNames = new Set<String>();
Set<Id> goalIds = new Set<Id>();
// the second set is not necessary but would be if you wanted to pull a different Id
for (SalesPlanGoal__c goal : goals)
{
    goalNames.add(goal.Name);
    goalIds.add(goal.Id);
}

List<SalesPlanActivity__c> activities = [
    SELECT Id FROM SalesPlanActivity__c
    WHERE SMART_Goal__c IN :goalIds
    AND Key_Initiative__c IN :goalNames
];
```

Answer (score 0):

I simplified the extension to...

```
public with sharing class SalesPlanPDFExtension{

public List<SalesPlanGoal__c> records = new List<SalesPlanGoal__c>();   

public List<SalesPlanGoal__c> getRecords() {    
    return records;
}

/*Constructor*/
public void SalesPlanPDFExtension() {  
}/*End Constructor*/

/*Constructor*/
public SalesPlanPDFExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    records = [SELECT Id,Name,Description__c,Sales_Plan__c,SMART_Goal_Objective__c,Key_Initiative__c,
                    (SELECT Id,Name,Account__c,Contact__c,Key_Initiative__c,Sales_Plan__c,SMART_Goal__c,Status__c,Subject__c 
                    FROM BenchmarkActivities__r)                
               FROM SalesPlanGoal__c 
               WHERE Sales_Plan__c=:ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')
               ORDER BY Name ASC
              ];
}   
/*End Constructor*/
}
```

I removed the second list and kept it simple with the `records` list. I modified the subquery to grab the activity records for each goal. I then changed the Visualforce to...

```
<!-- SMART GOAL INFORMATION -->
                <apex:repeat value="{!records}" var="init">
                    <tr>
                        <td>{!init.Name}</td>
                        <td>{!init.SMART_Goal_Objective__c}</td>
                        <td>
                            <!-- BENCHMARK ACTIVITIES -->
                            <apex:dataTable value="{!init.BenchmarkActivities__r}" var="ba" width="100%" columns="1" columnsWidth="100%" cellspacing="6">
                                <apex:column >
                                    <apex:outputText value="{!ba.Subject__c}" />
                                    <apex:outputPanel >
                                        <apex:outputText value=" " />
                                        <apex:outputField value="{!ba.Contact__c}" />
                                        <apex:outputText value=" " />
                                        <apex:outputField value="{!ba.Account__c}" />
                                    </apex:outputPanel>
                                    <br></br>
                                </apex:column>
                            </apex:dataTable>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                </apex:repeat>
```

What is different about the Visualforce is that the `apex:dataTable` now references the subquery as the value using the initial query variable and the child relationship name. Declaring a variable for the value allows me to create a second `apex:repeat` where I can get the records for the subquery related to the query.